# Controlling the scroll bar in my Android application

Tags: android, scroll

I have three linear sub layouts in my activity window in my Android application. Each layout has one scroll bar. My problem is when I am trying scroll in one layout area other layouts scroll bars also activating. Could you please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONE `<scrollView>` can hold at max ONE component inside it....... this ONE component can be either a layout holding several other views or further layouts inside it, or it can be a single view.

in order to have 3 separate scrolling linear layouts (meaning scrolling one linearLayout does not affect other LinearLayouts)..... you should have 3 separate `<ScrollView>` elements - each scrollview containing at max ONE of your THREE linearLayout.

for example:

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      all sub-components of **LinearLayout1** goes here
   <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      all sub-components of **LinearLayout2** goes here
   <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      all sub-components of **LinearLayout3** goes here
   <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Syed, thanks for the quick reply... however I am doing same above thing previously also. please check my below code snippet. update if i am wrong anywhere please...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollViewHead" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="10px"><LinearLayoutandroid:orientation="vertical"android:padding="10px"android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout></ScrollView> <!-- 2 more scrolls same AsAbov--></LinearLayout>

Comment: your code seems ok....... let me get this clear once again.... according to your first post, is your problem that all 3 of your linearLayouts get scrolled altogether when you scroll with one????? or is your problem that you don't want the scrollBAR to appear????

Comment: my problem is that when ever I am trying scroll(with mouse track ball) anywhere on the activity screen. top scroll view is activating. But I want one scroll view to work depending on in which layout my cursor is lying. please go through the link of my assignment and execute for your clear idea. link:  https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BzBFaFGkJY2kZDU2NTVmMjYtZGY0NC00MTNjLTliNTctNWQyNDc0ZTJiNTcx&hl=en&authkey=CN3n1roP